# How can I filter an array to make sure it does contain positions of another array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I am filtering my array in the following way:

```
randomArray = randomArray.filter({m in m.x < firstArray[0].x && ConditionX})
```

I have a another array `secondArray` which contains a elements which are in `randomArray`.
I would like to add another condition (to represent `ConditionX` in the code above) to the filter to remove all positions in `secondArray` from `randomArray`

Comment: Your question is worded a little funny. Can you show us more code with real examples so we can understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is `ConditionX` a condition in the first array? The second array? A conditional that has nothing to do with the array?

Comment: ConditionX is just representing the the second array that I want to be filtered from the `randomArray`

Comment: What do you mean by `want to be filtered`? The second array isn't in the first array so you can't filter it from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not understand exactly what you're trying to do here's a swing at basic array filtering.

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let array2 = ["c", "d", "e"]
var array3 = array1.filter() { return !array2.contains($0) }
```

That should return:

```
["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyStruct {
  var x: Int = 0

  init(_ x: Int) {
    self.x = x
  }
}

var randomArray = [MyStruct(1), MyStruct(2), MyStruct(3)]
var firstArray = [MyStruct(10)]
var secondArray = [MyStruct(1), MyStruct(2)]

func exist(_ item: MyStruct, in array: [MyStruct]) -> Bool {
  for i in array {
    if item.x == i.x {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

func shouldInclude(_ item: MyStruct, basedOn array: [MyStruct]) -> Bool {
  return item.x < array[0].x
}

randomArray = randomArray.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
  return shouldInclude(item, basedOn:firstArray) && !exist(item, in:secondArray)
})

print(randomArray) // output: [MyStruct(x: 3)]
```